# How can we source potassium fluoride outside of Earth?

Tags: solar-power, mining, natural-resources, reduced-gravity-manufacturing

[Potassium fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_fluoride) is the best known terrestrial option to purify the various materials used for the manufacturing of [photovoltaic panels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_resources#Solar_power). Many of these materials can be found in [regolith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regolith). The process most commonly used to produce potassium fluoride consists in dissolving potassium carbonate in hydrofluoric acid.

What would be the easiest way of sourcing such materials in the solar system outside of Earth? Ideally, this should be done using materials found on the Moon or some asteroids, with Mars being a last-resort option.

Alternatively, are there other options that should be considered?

Comment: Required, or simply the best option on Earth?

Comment: @chepner Excellent question! I really do not know. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most fluorine compounds are ultimately produced from [fluorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorite) mineral deposits, which in turn were produced hydrothermally, by hot water percolating through igneous rock. Particularly "felsic" rocks, a result of extended volcanic and tectonic activity, slow fractional crystallization or repeated re-melting and recrystallization of crust material, rather than something like basalt, which is produced directly from cooling mantle material.

The surface material on the moon is largely basalt, asteroids are composed of even more primitive material, and Ceres is probably the only asteroid with any extended history of liquid water. Mars has some felsic rocks, [such as granite](https://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2013/1119/Granite-on-Mars-Scientists-find-highly-evolved-rocks-on-Martian-surface), and a long history of liquid water, making it likely the best source for such minerals aside from Earth. As with many other elements, you will have to process a great deal of lunar or asteroid material to get any amount of fluorine, as it hasn't been concentrated by natural processes for you and is still largely uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 9):

The [formation of carbonates requires liquid water](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast04feb_1/).

[Potassium fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_fluoride) can be formed from [potassium carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_carbonate).

The Moon is yet to indicate it ever had liquid water, but Mars has had liquid water and [concentrations of potassium have been found on Mars](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/1244/potassium-concentrations-on-mars/?site=insight).

The most likely prospects for obtaining potassium fluoride outside Earth, in the solar system, is to go to Mars.

---

Edit:

[Fluorine was detected](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2014GL062742) in the Gale Crater.